# how to translate this mysql code in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I get 3 tables in my database. I want to know how to translate this mysql query in laravel. Here is the code:

```
SELECT item.id, item.libelle, entre.item_id, entre.total AS etotal, entre.prix_unitaire AS eprix, sortie.total AS stotal, sortie.prix_unitaire AS sprix, (entre.total - sortie.total) AS restant
FROM (
    SELECT id, libelle
    FROM items
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM entrees
        WHERE items.id = entrees.item_id
        AND date_entree = '23-10-2019'
    )
) item
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT item_id, prix_unitaire, sum(total) total
    FROM entrees 
    WHERE date_entree = '23-10-2019'
    GROUP BY item_id
) entre ON item.id = entre.item_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT item_id, prix_unitaire, sum(total) total
    FROM sorties 
    GROUP BY item_id
) sortie ON entre.item_id = sortie.item_id;
```

For table entrees [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqrtK.png)

For table items [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZURY.png)

For table sorties[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHpwm.png)

So please help me. And if possible explain me the query cause honestly I found it on another forum

Comment: Please include your code and any data in the post itself, not as an image. See: [mcve]. What have you tried to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let's break down your query into all the subqueries and then write them all together.

**Subquery 1**

```
SELECT id, libelle
FROM items
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM entrees
    WHERE items.id = entrees.item_id
    AND date_entree = '23-10-2019'
)
```

Translated to Query Builder:

```php
$subquery1 = DB::table('items')
->select('id', 'libelle')
->whereExists(function ($query) {
    $query->from('entrees')
    ->whereColumn('items.id', 'entrees.item_id')
    ->where('date_entree', '23-10-2019');
});
// You can verify this by dumping $subquery1->toSql() in the console.
```

**Subquery 2**

```
SELECT item_id, prix_unitaire, sum(total) total
FROM entrees 
WHERE date_entree = '23-10-2019'
GROUP BY item_id
```

Translated to Query Builder:

```php
$subquery2 = DB::table('entrees')
->select('item_id', 'prix_unitaire')
->selectRaw('sum(total) as total')
->where('date_entree', '23-10-2019')
->groupBy('item_id');
// You can verify this by dumping $subquery2->toSql() in the artisan console.
```

**Subquery 3**

```
SELECT item_id, prix_unitaire, sum(total) total
FROM sorties 
GROUP BY item_id
```

Translated to Query Builder:

```php
$subquery3 = DB::table('sorties')
->select('item_id', 'prix_unitaire')
->selectRaw('sum(total) as total')
->groupBy('item_id');
// You can verify this by dumping $subquery3->toSql() in the artisan console.
```

Now, to put it all together:

```php
$query = DB::table($subquery1, 'item')
->select(
    'item.id',
    'item.libelle',
    'entre.item_id',
    'entre.total as etotal',
    'entre.prix_unitaire as eprix',
    'sortie.total as stotal',
    'sotrie.prix_unitaire as sprix'
)
->selectRaw('(entre.total - sortie.total) as restant')
->leftJoinSub($subquery2, 'entre', function ($join) {
    $join->on('item.id', '=', 'entre.item_id');
})
->leftJoinSub($subquery3, 'sortie', function ($join) {
    $join->on('entre.item_id', '=', 'sortie.item_id');
});
// You can verify this by dumping $query->toSql() in the artisan console.
// To get the results, simply append the ->get() to the $query or do $query->get();
```

Below is a screen capture of this code being tested in the artisan console. The reason I'm using `$db->` instead of `DB::` is because I ran the following line before:

```php
$db = DB::connection('mysql');
```

which makes sure the query is translated to mysql when I use `toSql()`. Pay it no mind.
[image: Proof of concept in console.]
Everything I used can be found in [the official documentation about queries.](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries)

Comment: excuse me for waiting. that's what i look for. it's work for me. Thank you!